# Contact FileAs name

Tags: vba, outlook, contacts

I used the below document to fix existing contacts' FileAs entries. It didn't work for contacts that were company names.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/address-book/programmatically-change-the-display-format-for-all-contacts

Because the Firstname and Lastname fields were blank, it made the FileAs entry blank(" "+" "+" ").

How do I look for the blank FileAs field and set the CompanyName field as the FileAs field?

Comment: an ```if``` statement that checks if the first and last names are ```" "``` and if they are then ```companyname```.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Apparently I can't hit enter to skip a line in these comments?

Comment: 'Filter on the message class to obtain only contact items in the folder 
 Set contactItems = items.Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Contact'") 
 
 For Each itemContact In contactItems 
 If itemContact.FileAs = "" OR " " Then itemContact.FileAs=itemContact.Company
 itemContact.Save 
 Next

Comment: My question is more about the specifics and syntax, I am not a programmer. I wrote the above code to try and make this happen, but it tells me "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
Set contactItems = items.Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Contact'")
For Each itemContact In contactItems
'The underscore on the line below breaks the line into two lines.
'You need the left side of the equals for each condition in the if cant do or " "
    If itemContact.Firstname = "" Or itemContact.Firstname = " " _
    Or itemContact.lastname = "" or itemContact.lastname = " " Then
        itemContact.FileAs = itemContact.Company
        itemContact.Save
    end if
Next
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. much appreciated.